# how to add three button at bottom layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-button

i want to add three buttons at the bottom like this image
[image]
below listview  which is equal size  my code is below help me how do i add this three button in my layout  this is my screen
[image: http://imgur.com/DbQJTqU]

```
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/test_button_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test_button_text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/test_button_image"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test_button_image"
            android:text="San Diego Unified"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="25sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test_button_text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/test_button_text2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/test_button_text2"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="SCHOOL DISTRICT"
            android:textColor="#000000" >
        </TextView>
     </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:background="@drawable/border1" 
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"

            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="HEALTHY BODIES HEALTHY MINDS "
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="11sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"

            android:background = "@null"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="40dp"
             android:background = "@null"
              android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/twitter"
            android:text="Button Text" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:background="#00FFFF"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

    android:hint="Search School By Name"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

  </EditText>
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
    android:src="@drawable/title_search" />

 </RelativeLayout>

     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCaption"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:text="SELECT A SCHOOL TO VIEW LUNCH OR BREAKFAST MENUS"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txtCopyright"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
         android:background="@drawable/border2" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/lytTitlebar"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listMainMenu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_selector"
            android:dividerHeight="1dip"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true" />
    </LinearLayout>



  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: With which part exactly do you have problem?

Comment: i didn't understand which 3 buttons are you reffering ..., Are facebook and twitter buttons?

Comment: in sample screen http://imgur.com/2ZtcoIB  see three button at bottom Farm to school Take a survey  share this app  i wana create this three buttonin my app which are horizontaly align and same size how i do that? how i create same Ui  inmy screen at bottom?

Comment: i wanna create below my listiew thre button (Farm to school, take a survery , share this app   and same backgroup how i do that?

Comment: Using Linear layout also its possible but for best result I would suggest you to do your design by Relative Layout.It would be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

Take one linear layout below listview and give its orientation as horizontal and then add three textview one after the other with a seperator(i.e using View) and then put a click event on each and every textview and use it and put that linear layout gravity  = bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution...

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/border" >
<Button 1>
<Button 2>-center horizontal and center vertical
<Button 3>-align parent right- true
```

Add what further properties you want to add in button.

Comment: I think you have got your answer.